# Confusion with selectors, div ~ h1 vs div > h1

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am having a problem understanding the `div ~ h1`, it appears it selects all h1 tags that directly follow a div.

But isn't this what `div > h1` actually does ?

It selects all h1 that is a direct child of the div ?

I also came across `div + h1` and at first i was confused, but this appears to select only a single element i.e 1 H1 tag that follows a div.

Comment: I do. It shows no research effort. There are hundreds of references and tutorials out there that explain this simple concept quite clearly. Not to mention testing the different test cases is quite basic.

Comment: @MikeHometchko Probably because all it takes is reading the descriptions from the spec [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/general), [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/child), and [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/adjacent).

Comment: God forbid somebody wants to, I don't know, ask a community of experienced developers because it exists and is arguably the best resource on the internet for interactive learning?  You elitists are so strange to me.

Comment: What's elitist about "rtfm" or "please google first"? You're right, SO _is_ a great resource. But guess what... there are existing answers right here on SO for what each of these combinators do.

Comment: I initially had a little confusion between the selectors, the question has now been answered and i hope my question with the answer provides quicker results to those who google. Feel free to downgrade the question, I believe it was a honest question that i wanted some clarification on. And it was answered, thank you everyone that helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`div ~ h1` will select **all** the `h1` following siblings [brothers] (not just the immediate one).

`div + h1` will select only the **immediate** brother `h1` following the div.

`div > h1` will select **all** the `h1` that are **direct children** of the div.

`div h1` will select **all** the `h1` that are **nested** in the div (not just direct children).

all of that, and more can be found [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)

Comment: Out of interest then, whats teh difference between the div ~ h1  and div h1 ...... the div h1, will select all h1 that follow a div ?

Comment: I've added an answer to that in my answer.

Comment: @Martin the `div h1` will select all `h1` in the `div`.

Answer (score 1):

```
p ~ ul
```

The ~ selects every UL element that are preceded by a P element

```
body > P
```

Sets the style of all P elements that are children of BODY.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

### In other words

The ~ selector uses an immediate predecessor clause whereas the > is more general, targeting all children no matter how far from their parent.

Comment: but this is technically the same ... Body > P selects ALL direct children that a P from the body ?

Comment: The [general sibling selector (`~`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) is more akin the [adjacent sibling selector (`+`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) than the child combinatator selector. The child combinatator selector is not more ambiguous, it's fundamentally different.

Comment: @steveax you are quite correct ambiguous was the wrong word, general (as it is the apparent name) is much more fitting.

Comment: I think you missed my main point: child selectors and sibling selectors are fundamentally different.